# How to show data specific column wise in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have GridView, I want to set data like specific column-wise, ex. There is four column the first column contains date second have number third have the name and the fourth one should be valued, so how I can show like this in GridView.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a custom ListView.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to find module of position inside of adapter need to set value as per position modulo like following is the example,

```
int modulo=postion%4;
if(modulo==0){
//set Here Date in view
}else if(modulo==1){
//set Here Number in view
}else if(modulo==2){
//set Here Name in view
}else if(modulo==3){
//set Here Valued in view
}
```

inside you adapter write above code